# Get data from variable z where variable x = variable y

Tags: r, match

```
library(dplyr)
df = data.frame(group_id = c(rep("a",5), rep("b",5)),
                prod_id = 1:10,
                prod_type = rep(c("a","a", "b", "c","d"),2),
                start = lubridate::dmy(c("01/01/2001", "02/02/2002", "03/03/2003", "04/04/2004", "05/05/2005")),
                fin = lubridate::dmy(c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)))%>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(next_acd = if_else(lead(prod_type) %in% c("a","c","d"), lead(prod_id), prod_id[NA])) %>%
  tidyr::fill(next_acd, .direction = "up")

df
group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin    next_acd
   <chr>      <int> <chr>     <date>     <date>    <int>
 1 a              1 a         2001-01-01 NA            2
 2 a              2 a         2002-02-02 NA            4
 3 a              3 b         2003-03-03 NA            4
 4 a              4 c         2004-04-04 NA            5
 5 a              5 d         2005-05-05 NA           NA
 6 b              6 a         2001-01-01 NA            7
 7 b              7 a         2002-02-02 NA            9
 8 b              8 b         2003-03-03 NA            9
 9 b              9 c         2004-04-04 NA           10
10 b             10 d         2005-05-05 NA           NA
```

In the above `next_acd` is the next `prod_id` that is `prod_type` "a","c" or "d".

I now want to `mutate` `fin` to be the `start` date of the `prod_id` that corresponds with `next_acd`. Result should be:

```
 group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin        next_acd
   <chr>      <int> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <int>
 1 a              1 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        2
 2 a              2 a         2002-02-02 2004-04-04        4
 3 a              3 b         2003-03-03 2004-04-04        4
 4 a              4 c         2004-04-04 2005-05-05        5
 5 a              5 d         2005-05-05 NA               NA
 6 b              6 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        7
 7 b              7 a         2002-02-02 2004-04-04        9
 8 b              8 b         2003-03-03 2004-04-04        9
 9 b              9 c         2004-04-04 2005-05-05       10
10 b             10 d         2005-05-05 NA               NA
```

**EDIT**
The original answer works with the example data, where the `prod_id` are in numerical order without any missing. It doesn't work in my real data which is more like:

```
df = data.frame(group_id = c("G1","G1", rep("G2",8)),
                prod_id = c(1,2,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12),
                prod_type = rep(c("a","a", "b", "c","d"),2),
                start = lubridate::dmy(c("01/01/2001", "02/02/2002",
                                         "05/05/2005","06/06/2006", "07/07/2007", "08/08/2008", "09/09/2009","01/01/2010", "02/02/2011", "03/03/2012" )),
                fin = lubridate::dmy(NA))%>%
  group_by(group_id) %>%
  mutate(next_acd = if_else(lead(prod_type) %in% c("a","c","d"), lead(prod_id), prod_id[NA])) %>%
  tidyr::fill(next_acd, .direction = "up")%>%
  ungroup()
```

The result I'm expecting is:

```
group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin        next_acd
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <dbl>
 1 G1             1 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        2
 2 G1             2 a         2002-02-02 NA               NA
 3 G2             5 b         2005-05-05 2006-06-06        6
 4 G2             6 c         2006-06-06 2007-07-07        7
 5 G2             7 d         2007-07-07 2008-08-08        8
 6 G2             8 a         2008-08-08 2009-09-09        9
 7 G2             9 a         2009-09-09 2011-02-02       11
 8 G2            10 b         2010-01-01 2011-02-02       11
 9 G2            11 c         2011-02-02 2012-03-03       12
10 G2            12 d         2012-03-03 NA               NA
```

But trying `df$fin <- df$start[df$prod_id[df$next_acd]]`,  I get:

```
df
# A tibble: 10 x 6
   group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin        next_acd
   <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <dbl>
 1 G1             1 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        2
 2 G1             2 a         2002-02-02 NA               NA
 3 G2             5 b         2005-05-05 2010-01-01        6
 4 G2             6 c         2006-06-06 2011-02-02        7
 5 G2             7 d         2007-07-07 2012-03-03        8
 6 G2             8 a         2008-08-08 NA                9
 7 G2             9 a         2009-09-09 NA               11
 8 G2            10 b         2010-01-01 NA               11
 9 G2            11 c         2011-02-02 NA               12
10 G2            12 d         2012-03-03 NA               NA
```

I don't understand what is happening here or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution, in `base R`:

```r
df$fin <- df$start[match(df$next_acd, df$prod_id)]

#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#>    group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin        next_acd
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <dbl>
#>  1 G1             1 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        2
#>  2 G1             2 a         2002-02-02 NA               NA
#>  3 G2             5 b         2005-05-05 2006-06-06        6
#>  4 G2             6 c         2006-06-06 2007-07-07        7
#>  5 G2             7 d         2007-07-07 2008-08-08        8
#>  6 G2             8 a         2008-08-08 2009-09-09        9
#>  7 G2             9 a         2009-09-09 2011-02-02       11
#>  8 G2            10 b         2010-01-01 2011-02-02       11
#>  9 G2            11 c         2011-02-02 2012-03-03       12
#> 10 G2            12 d         2012-03-03 NA               NA
```

---

Or using `dplyr`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(fin = start[match(next_acd, prod_id)])

#> # A tibble: 10 × 6
#>    group_id prod_id prod_type start      fin        next_acd
#>    <chr>      <dbl> <chr>     <date>     <date>        <dbl>
#>  1 G1             1 a         2001-01-01 2002-02-02        2
#>  2 G1             2 a         2002-02-02 NA               NA
#>  3 G2             5 b         2005-05-05 2006-06-06        6
#>  4 G2             6 c         2006-06-06 2007-07-07        7
#>  5 G2             7 d         2007-07-07 2008-08-08        8
#>  6 G2             8 a         2008-08-08 2009-09-09        9
#>  7 G2             9 a         2009-09-09 2011-02-02       11
#>  8 G2            10 b         2010-01-01 2011-02-02       11
#>  9 G2            11 c         2011-02-02 2012-03-03       12
#> 10 G2            12 d         2012-03-03 NA               NA
```

Comment: This answer worked with the example, but not my real data. I've added new example data

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @MarkDavies. If I have some time later on, I will have a look at your new dataset.

Comment: My updated solution solves the problem, @MarkDavies.